# No such test method / unbound error

Tags: python, unit-testing, class-method

I have overridden the unittest.TestCase class to include some additional functionality like this

```
class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def foo(self):
        return 4711
```

which I am going to use in the `setUpClass` call in a Test Case like this

```
class MyTest(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        value = cls.foo() #1 
        value = MyTest.foo() #2
        value = MyTest().foo() #3
        value = TestCase().foo() #4
```

where I fail to access the function `foo()` I have implemented in the modified unitest class.

I can see that try #2 will fail because I try to access a method of a class which is not instantiated, and foo is not a classmethod.
I can see that try #1 also does not work, as I am trying to access a non-class method from the classmethod level (or how this ever is correctly described).
But why is try #3/#4 giving me an `no such test method` error?

How is it possible to access the `foo()` method WITHOUT making it a classmethod (because I cannot change this as it is something external)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a hack, but it works:

```
TestCase.__dict__['foo'](None)
```